# SetID session with symfony2

Tags: php, session, symfony, session-variables

I have a problem with sessions in symfony2.

I have a own session class. I have a $key with id of a session. And I want to set a new session with this id.

In PHP I used:

```
session_id($key);
```

But, if I use in symfony2 this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session as sfsession;
...
sfsession::setId($key);
```

But execution of my site fails and doesn't say me an error.

Comment: [Try to find a _static_ `setId` method here](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session.html#method_set), but don't waste your time: it's not there. Pass an instance of [`SessionStorageInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/SessionStorage/SessionStorageInterface.html) to the constructor if you want to set the id, or use _the public `set` method_

Comment: Please look in you're php_error log and post the error that is produced.

Comment: If I use SessionStorageInterface::setId($key); the PHP_error log say: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot call abstract method Symfony\\Component\\HttpFound
ation\\Session\\Storage\\SessionStorageInterface::setId()